# Looking for a easier cleaner way to save ajax POST data to a django model and avoid hardcoding for saving?

Tags: ajax, django, models, save

I have been working on a django project that requires a large amount of user input and processing and am sick of hardcoding the data in the view in order to save it to my models as seen below.

```
mymodel = TheModel.objects.get(id=model.id)
mymodel.name = request.POST.get('name')
mymodel.zip  = request.POST.get('zip')
...
mymodel.save()
```

Except instead of two model attributes like I used above there are sometimes up to 25 that need to be saved.

I am using ajax to serialize the forms and send them to my views where they are saved. I am looking for the cleanest way possible to get around this problem. Less code the better and I am willing to reformat my models if there is a way that significantly shortens the number of lines of code I have now.

Thanks

Comment: Is the name of the key in the POST data always exactly the same as the name of the attribute on the model?

Comment: You should use ModelForm which is able to save a whole new dataset or update an already existing instance. You should have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: thanks. no the input names are not always the same as the model attribute names but I am going to change that. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to have a look at [`ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Answer (score 0):

This method will work, although you have to be careful to add a model field / ajax parameter at the sametime for it to work

Given:

Form1

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="parameter1" />
  <input name="parameter2" />
  <input name="parameter3" />
</form>
```

Write javascript code so the data going across the wire looks like this JSON (form serialization
will probably not work)

```
{ parameter1 : "some data", "parameter2" : "some data", parameter3 : "some data" }
```

Then, you have a django model that looks like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.StringField()
    parameter2 = models.StringField()
    parameter3 = models.StringField()
```

You can save/update with code like this:

params = dict(request.POST)

```
m = MyModel.objects.create(**params)
```

or

```
m = MyModel.objects.get(id=ID)
m.update(force_update=False,**params)
```

If your parameters do not line up the code will fail though.